# Getting Data from HTTP on click

Tags: angular, angular5

I am learning angular ( using angular 5). In the project I have to GET data via HTTP and on click of each element i have to display the details.

I am able to Get the data via HTTP and also able to get details based on clicked element. But I cant show the details, or in other words I dont know how can i show the details.

Here what I have tried.

```
allEntry = [];
onClickData = [];
 getAllData = function() {
        this.httpClient.get(this.resourceUrl)
            .subscribe(
                (data: any[]) => {
                    this.allEntry = data;
                }
            )
    }


    onClick(id: number) {
        const myData = this.allEntry .find((element) => element.id === id)
        console.log(myData)
        this.onClickData = myData;
    }
```

The templete

```
<div *ngFor ="let el of allEntry ">
   <button (click)="onClick(el.id)">{{el.name}}</button> 

</div>

<div *ngFor ="let e of onClickData">
    {{e.title}}
{{e.age}}
{{e.name}}
</div>
```

each entry in allEntry contains id,title, name and age. now show i have to display the details on click of a name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngFor` only works for arrays. `onClickData` is an object. To display it properly you should use

```
<div *ngIf="onClickData">
    {{onClickData.title}}
    {{onClickData.age}}
    {{onClickData.name}}
</div>
```

Notice the `ngIf`. This prevents the div from rendering until `onClickData` exists. This will prevent any errors when `onClickData` is undefined.

Alternatively you can use the safe navigation opertor

```
<div>
    {{onClickData?.title}}
    {{onClickData?.age}}
    {{onClickData?.name}}
</div>
```

---

Sidenote: You do not need to do the `.find()` in your onClick event handler. That handler has access to the entire element. So you can simply pass in the entire object to your method and store it.

```
// component.html
<div *ngFor ="let el of allEntry ">
    <button (click)="onClick(el)">{{el.name}}</button> 
</div>

// component.ts
onClick(el){
    this.onClickData = el;
}
```